# Depth to point cloud

Tags: c++, opencv, type-conversion, point-cloud-library, depth-buffer

I'm trying to create a point cloud from a depth video frame, which has pixel values between 0 and 4500 (recorded from the kinect v2).
So if i do `cout << depth` i can see those values.
Now i try to create a point cloud using PCL with

```
 for (int y = 0; y < depthImageSize.height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < depthImageSize.width; ++x)
        {
            pcl::PointXYZRGBA &pt = result->at(x, y);

            float depthValue = (float) depth.at<float>(y, x);

            pt.x = (static_cast<float>(x) - centerX) * scaleFactorX * depthValue;
            pt.y = (centerY - static_cast<float>(y)) * scaleFactorY * depthValue;
            pt.z = depthValue;
         }
    }
```

I found this depth to point cloud conversion plenty of times while researching. The float conversion of `(float) depth.at<float>(y, x);`does not result in the same values between 0 and 4500 though, it results in values like -6.54209e+35, 1.82232e-40 or -nan.

Any idea why the conversion fails?

Comment: What is the type of `depth`?

Comment: If it's an OpenCV `Mat`, I would make sure you're indexing correctly. `at` only checks ranges in Debug builds. It sounds like you're accidentally indexing out of range.

Comment: It is an OpenCV `Mat` Typeid is N2cv3MatE

Comment: It's the same if I use `cv::MatIterator_` instead

Comment: Can you print the value at that location before you attempt to convert it? How are you initializing/filling your matrix? Try to initialize the matrix to zero before anything else.

Comment: Are you sure the type is float?